# PyQt6: QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

Consider the following class that implements QThread:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread

from stream_consumer.streaming_worker import StreamingWorker

class GuiStreamerController:

    def __init__(self, callback_function) -> None:
        """Initialize the class
        
        Args:
            callback_function (function): The GUI function that will process results in the GUI thread.
        """

        self._thread = QThread()
        self._worker = StreamingWorker(callback_function)
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)
        self._thread.started.connect(self._worker.run)

        self._is_running = False
    
    def run(self, local_stream_message_criteria=None) -> None:
        """Start the streaming process.
        
        Args:
            local_stream_message_criteria (StreamMessageCriteria): The stream message criteria. Optional.
        
        - Starts the Qthread (which starts the streaming process.)
          - Implicitly calls the *StreamingWorker* *run* method (assigned in this class' __init__)
        """

        if self._is_running:
            return
        
        if local_stream_message_criteria:
            self._worker.stream_from_local(local_stream_message_criteria)
        
        self._thread.start()
        self._is_running = True

    def quit(self) -> None:
        """Quit the streaming process."""

        self._worker.quit()
        self._thread.quit()
```

Now consider this very simple testing script:

```
...
class TestQCoreApplication:
    def test_functionality(self):

        self.app = QCoreApplication([])

        self.streamer = GuiStreamerController(_handle_stream_result)
        
        self.streamer.run(local_stream_message_criteria)
        print('Streamer Started')

        QTest.qWait(5000)

        self.streamer.quit()
        print('Streamer Quit')

        self.app.quit()

# Block 1
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     test = TestQCoreApplication()
#     test.test_functionality()

# Block 2
# test = TestQCoreApplication()
# test.test_functionality()

# Block 3
def test_this():
    test = TestQCoreApplication()
    test.test_functionality()

test_this()
```

This, mostly,runs as expected, except the call to self.streamer.quit() raises the following error:

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

However, if I comment out "Block 3" and enable either "Block 1" or "Block 2", it works fine.

Sorry this is not a completely reproducible example, as there is just way too much code. However, I think the answer to the issue stems from QCoreApplication being called from within a function, so I am hoping somebody can provide a simple explanation and workaround to that.

Please note, I have tried calling wait() on the QThread, and it just hangs indefinitely. If I give it a timeout, the error still comes at the end of it.

Please also note that my end goal is to run tests from PyTest / pytest-qt, but I am getting the same error. My thinking is, if I can solve this simple example, I can solve it in PyTest.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that, aside from GuiStreamerController functioning as expected when run under QCoreApplication, called from the root of a script, it also runs as expected when called inside a QApplication loop.

As another experiment, I created the following class:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QCoreApplication

from stream_consumer.gui_streamer_controller import GuiStreamerController

class StreamRunner:

    def __init__(
            self,
            local_stream_message_criteria,
            max_results: int = None) -> None:

        self._max_results = max_results
        self._local_stream_message_criteria = local_stream_message_criteria
        self._app = QCoreApplication([])
        self._streamer = GuiStreamerController(self._handle_stream_result)
        self._result_count = 0
        self._results = []
    
    @property
    def result_count(self):
        """Return the number of stream results"""
        return self._result_count
    
    @property
    def results(self):
        """Return the stream results"""
        return self._results

    def run(self):
        """Start a stream run."""""

        self._streamer.run(self._local_stream_message_criteria)
        # THIS TIME exec is called!!!!
        self._app.exec()
    
    def _quit(self) -> None:
        """Quit a stream run."""

        self._streamer.quit()
        self._app.quit()
    
    def _handle_stream_result(self, result):
        """Handle the stream results"""
        
        self._results.append(result)
        self._result_count += 1

        if self._max_results and self._result_count >= self._max_results:
            self._quit()
```

On line 33 it calls *exec()*, closer mimicking what happens when run under QApplication. However, as with my earlier script, if I instantiate this class, and call its *run()* method from the root of a script, everything is fine, but if I call it from a function, I get the same issue.

Comment: What exactly does `worker.quit()` do? Because whatever that is, it doesn't seem to live up to its billing. The thread cannot quit until `worker.run()` returns. If `thread.wait()` hangs, that implies `worker.quit()` is either broken, or just doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It shuts down some loops in ray.io (multiprocessing) actors, allowing those objects to go out of scope. As you'll see from my update, everything is functioning without issue when run in a QApplication loop, so I can only think there is a subtle difference in QCoreApplication that I am unaware of. It is especially perplexing that it runs fine from the root of a script but not a function in that script.

Comment: @HapiDaze Conceptually speaking, there shouldn't be any difference in QCoreApplication or QApplication for that purpose. In fact, the *important* difference is that in your first code you never start the event loop.

Comment: The reason for not starting the event loop is because I wanted a simple way to then test methods on the GuiStreamerController object, but as my StreamRunner class demonstrates, even when I do, the same error shows up when it is not called from the root of a script. It seems very odd to me, that both classes work just fine from the root, but not from a function. That is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: @HapiDaze One part of the issue is probably garbage-collection. With block 3, the `test` object will be deleted as soon as `test_this` returns, whereas with the others, it will occur upon script exit. This may change the order in which certain objects are deleted. If you make `app` and/or `test` global, does that make any difference? (PS: please also check whether `thread.wait()` still hangs with the new example).

Comment: @ekhumoro, Yes! Adding *global test* as the first line of *test_this* has stopped the error. I now need to figure out how to do this as a PyTest test, but I'm guessing I can carry that same logic over somehow. Thank you! I think this is definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: @ekhumoro. With regard to thread.wait(), that does still hang, but I'm not sure it's an issue to me.

Comment: @HapiDaze My suggestion to try using `global` is just a debugging hack that bypasses the real problem. The error isn't actually *caused* by the garbage-collection issue. If `worker.quit()` did its job properly, the order of deletion wouldn't matter, since the thread would have already terminated cleanly.

Comment: The functionality combines multithreading and multiprocessing, so there's been a bunch of potential gotchas. However, in production, the code only ever runs in a QApplication loop, fired up from the application root, and I've not experienced this problem or any other. This whole thing has been a hack, purely to facilitate some very specific testing within my PyTest suite. With that in mind, I'm not too worried if this piece is a little brittle. Thanks for the warning though!

Comment: @HapiDaze As ekhumoro properly suggests, if making `test` global works, then it's just a confirmation of the symptom. The problem is probably not there (globals are often cause of misunderstanding, unless you *really* know how to use them), and quite probably relies on `worker.quit()`, as said since the beginning. You're also saying that the actual code uses multiprocessing *other than* multithreading, something you ***never*** properly mentioned in the original question nor properly explained in your comments. Even if the `global` workaround worked, this doesn't mean that your code is valid.

Comment: @HapiDaze This means that even if the `global` solution works, you probably only solved the symptom, not the real problem. Blowing your nose with a tissue doesn't make a cold go away, and if you don't properly cure that cold, more problems may arise. Dealing with multithreading and multiprocessing adds complexities that cannot be ignored, and the common "if it works, it's fine" doesn't really work anymore. As said above, using `global` only bypasses the problem without actually solving it: it may surface again later, in even worse and hard to solve situations.

Comment: @HapiDaze I think you may be missing the point. From what you've said so far, it seems there are *no circumstances* (during testing or otherwise) in which the thread terminates cleanly. Thus, calling `streamer.quit()` (or whatever) is effectively a NO-OP. Up until now, it seems your application has been largely unaffected by this brokenness (which has only been exposed now as a side-effect of unpredictable garbage-collection). Personally, I would be tempted to remove that API altogether so I never inadvertently came to rely on something that only pretends to do what it says it does.

Answer (score 5):

The `worker.quit()` method is designed to terminate loops or processes within the `StreamingWorker` object, which seems to be managing tasks asynchronously, potentially using `ray.io` for multiprocessing. However, the effectiveness of `worker.quit()` in stopping the `QThread` gracefully appears to be in question. If `worker.run()` does not return, the thread remains active, causing the `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` error.

The issue seems to be exacerbated when `QCoreApplication` is initiated within a function rather than at the root of the script. This could relate to how the `Qt` event loop is managed and terminated, and the lifecycle of objects within that loop. Running under `QApplication`, which typically includes an event loop, does not present the same issue, suggesting the problem is tied to the event loop's management or the absence thereof.

The discussion in comments points towards an issue with garbage collection and the lifespan of the test objects. When the objects are declared globally, they persist for the duration of the script, alleviating the immediate error. This suggests that the destruction order of objects (due to garbage collection) when declared within a function might be contributing to the issue.

Using a global variable to fix the issue is identified as a workaround that addresses the symptom rather than the underlying problem. The real issue likely lies with how `worker.quit()` fails to ensure the thread's clean termination. Relying on such workarounds without addressing the fundamental problem could lead to more significant, harder-to-diagnose issues later, especially when dealing with the complexities of multithreading and multiprocessing.

Also in comments, the discussion suggests reconsidering the design and implementation of the `quit()` functionality. Ensuring that `worker.quit()` and any related cleanup methods effectively manage thread termination and resource cleanup is crucial, particularly in testing scenarios where the application's behaviour might differ from production.

The original issue appears to stem from how `worker.quit()` is implemented and its inability to guarantee the `QThread`'s termination. This issue is magnified by the nuances of object lifespan and garbage collection when running within a `QCoreApplication` initiated from a function.
A more robust solution might involve ensuring that `worker.quit()` reliably stops all background operations and signals the thread to terminate cleanly. This might involve implementing additional synchronisation mechanisms or conditions within `StreamingWorker` to ensure `run()` can exit gracefully when quit() is called.

For testing, especially with frameworks like PyTest, ensuring the consistent setup and teardown of the test environment is important. This might involve revisiting how `QCoreApplication` is managed, possibly using fixtures to control the lifecycle of the application and streaming objects.
Lastly, this discussion underscores the importance of thoroughly understanding and correctly managing the interaction between multithreading, multiprocessing, and the Qt event loop, particularly in complex asynchronous operations.